# Cosa vuol dire "volatino"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Io mi sono frustato tanto come te, solo che io non ne parlo mai e se mi viene del male lo nascondo, per forte che sia. Cosa ti credi, t’è passato di mente che ho sessantadue anni, e che lavoro tanto che altro che perdere il sangue, se avessi anch’io il buco da perderlo! E giusto che parlavi del fieno, lo sai cosa vuol dire alla mia età tagliare il fieno da quando il sole si leva a quando si corica? Da giovani come i tuoi figli e con la rugiada son tutti buoni a tagliare, ma quando il sole viene alto e il fieno mette il pelo **volatino**, allora sí che il fieno ti domanda quanti anni hai! Ecco, se è per la questione del fieno!

Qualcuno di voi mi sa spiegare cosa significa "volatino"? Non ho trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un vocabolo di origine piemontese?

Comment: cercando per varie foto di spighe di frumento ho scoperto che i filamenti sottili della spiga (es. https://www.lapappadolce.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/grano.jpg) si chiamano ariste (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/arista/), immagino sia il "pelo" di cui si parla.
Il brano parla della fatica sotto il solleone, quindi quando è agosto e la spiga è secca; immagino che in questi casi i semi si stacchino e volino via e da qui arrivi l'aggettivo "volatino" - ma questo è un mio volo di fantasia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il fieno in passato veniva tagliato principalmente con la falce per cui era molto più facile e meno faticoso tagliarlo bagnato dalla rugiada, meglio se al mattino presto.

Quando il sole viene alto anche l'erba si alza (mette il pelo volatino, diventa volante) e viene magari mossa dal vento, diventa molto più faticosa da tagliare con la falce.

Il senso del passaggio è che quando si è giovani e si taglia il fieno dall'alba al tramonto è molto più facile sopportare la fatica, ma quando si diventa anziani e non si hanno più le energie di un tempo il fieno diventa quasi un avversario che ti mette a dura prova, facendoti rendere conto dell'età che hai raggiunto.

Comment: Tutto questo mi è chiaro, ma cosa significa "volatino"? Che si alza come se volasse?

Comment: Esatto, la rugiada bagna l'erba e al rende più consistente al taglio della falce. Quando l'erba si asciuga a causa del sole si alza, diventa volante. Volatino ha la stessa origine di volantino, dal francese volant.